# Connections for PostgreSQL Listen Notify

Tags: postgresql

I have a PHP script that listens to the NOTIFY triggered by a PostgreSQL trigger.
When my script "hears" the notification it executes other commands inside this loop, like SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc...

```
Eg.: $conn->exec('LISTEN "notify_hello"');

while (1) {
    $result = "";
    // wait for one Notify 10seconds instead of using sleep(10)
    $result = $conn->pgsqlGetNotify(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 10000);

    if ( $result ) {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare ( 'SELECT * FROM table' );

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is not related to programming or how to use `LISTEN`, but directly with the database.

Currently I take advantage of the already open connection with the database to perform the other DQL/DML operations inside the loop, my question is, if I can use this already open connection, because theoretically it is busy monitoring the notifications of PostgreSQL's `NOTIFY` resource or if I should create a new connection whenever I run a DQL/DML command and terminate them after the operation I performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your current approach as long as you are satisfied with a single thread executing the requests one after the other. You won't lose a notification just because it arrives while you are running some SQL statement.

If you want several threads to execute the requests concurrently, you could start a new connection and a new thread for that. However, it is wasteful to open a database connection for only a single request. A better solution would be to have a number of workers that each have their database connection, and you assign the task to some worker that is currently idle.